# PHP Variable not getting assigned after a successful run

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I've got a script to register a new user into the database, and it works fine - the user does get put into the database. However, the variable $success does not get changed to 1(even though it should be, because the query is successful). Every time I call this function, it returns the value of $success as 0. 
The only thing I can think of is if the query still runs fine, but returns FALSE. But that wouldn't really make much sense when it is updating the table with the correct information?

```
  public function register($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $employee_number) {
                  //Lets us know if we registered properly or not
                  $success = 0;
                  //Salt and encrypt the password
                  $salt = generateSalt($password);
                  $encypted_password = generatePassword($salt, $password);
                  if(isset($this->db)) {
                          if($this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (email, encrypted_password, salt, first_name, last_name, employee_number) VALUES('$email', '$encypted_password', '$salt', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$employee_number');")) {
                                  $success = 1;
                          }

                  }       
                  $arr = array("success" => $success);
                  return json_encode($arr);   
          }
```

EDIT: I knew I was forgetting to mention something, this is using SQLite3. According to the documentation(http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php), it will return an SQLite3Object if the query returns results. HOWEVER, if it does not return results it should just return TRUE if the query succeeded, or FALSE if the query failed. 
Double checking the var_dump of the statement, I am getting back NULL. Last I knew, INSERT statements were not supposed to return anything, so this is a bit strange.

Comment: What SQL Engine are you using? have you tried removing the semicolon (;) at the end?

Comment: try `$result = $this->db->query(...); var_dump($result);` see what's REALLY being returned by the db call.

Comment: If you're using CI, try `$this->db->_error_message();` inside your `if` block to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try assigning the value to a variable then checking the variables value. If nothing else you can var_dump() the variable and see what the function IS outputting.

```
public function register($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $employee_number) {
                  //Lets us know if we registered properly or not
                  $success = 0;
                  //Salt and encrypt the password
                  $salt = generateSalt($password);
                  $encypted_password = generatePassword($salt, $password);
                  if(isset($this->db)) {
                          $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (email, encrypted_password, salt, first_name, last_name, employee_number) VALUES('$email', '$encypted_password', '$salt', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$employee_number');";
                          if($query === true)) {
                                  $success = 1;
                          }

                  }       
                  $arr = array("success" => $success);
                  return json_encode($arr);   
          }
```

Edit: Since you know now what the function is returning. you can always set the check to

```
if($query !== false){
    $success = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echo'ing before/after the "$success = 1;" to see whether you are actually getting into that part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the mannual of class you are using to insert data into the database table.

```
$this->db->query()
```

and also check what value the above function is returning. The above function can give you a better answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the return value of $this->db->query(), which is impossible to know without its code or documentation here. For all I know, query() may not return anything. I would save the return value of query() into a variable and then dump it as part of your return for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your inner if statement to a try/catch block.  See if an exception is being thrown.  It's possible that you're getting a warning so even though it works, it isn't ever reaching the inner block to set $success = 1.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the database classe that you use.

One of the solution would be to call an "insert" function instead of the query function. This should return a proper result.

Another solution would be to make another query and try to fetch the data you've just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging around and asking a couple co-workers I discovered that the person who was working on this before me wrote a wrapper class for SQLite3 databases that uses almost the exact same syntax as what comes built in with PHP - same function names, parameters and everything. There was even a link in the comments that led to the PHP website detailing SQLite3. I've got it figured out from here, thanks for the suggestions everyone.